# My on_member_join event is not working. I tried intents, but it gives this error

Tags: python, pycharm, discord, discord.py

Consider:

> st recent call last): 
> File "randomgg.py", line 1271, in \u003cmodule\u003e 
> client.run(token) 
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 708, in run 
> return future.result() 
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 687, in runner 
> await self.start(*args, **kwargs) 
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 651, in start 
> await self.connect(reconnect=reconnect) 
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 586, in connect 
> raise PrivilegedIntentsRequired(exc.shard_id) from None 
> discord.errors.PrivilegedIntentsRequired: Shard ID None is requesting privileged intents that have not been explicitly enabled in the developer portal. It is recommended to go to https://discord.com/developers/applications/ and explicitly enable the privileged intents within your application's page. If this is not possible, then consider disabling the privileged intents instead. \

My code was

```
import aiohttp
import discord
import asyncio
from collections import Counter
import typing
from discord.ext import commands
import os
from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions
import random
import json
from discord import Status
from asyncio import gather
from discord.utils import get
import datetime
from discord.utils import get
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.', intents=intents)
client.remove_command('help')

def check_if_it_is_me(ctx):
    return ctx.message.author.id == 465946367622381578

@client.event
async def status_task():
    while True:
        await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.idle, activity=discord.Game('status1'))
        await asyncio.sleep(4)
        await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.idle, activity=discord.Game('status2'))
        await asyncio.sleep(4)
        await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.idle, activity=discord.Game('status3'))
        await asyncio.sleep(4)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user.name} is ready')
    client.loop.create_task(status_task())

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    mem_join = member.joined_at
    guild_create = member.created_at
    join_days = (mem_join - guild_create).days
    role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id=714805001918349344)
    channel = discord.utils.get(member.guild.channels, id=771081754038501376)
    if join_days < 10:
        await channel.send(f'{role.mention} {member} is suspicious of being an alt, he joined {join_days} after creating his account. Pls keep an eye on him')

@client.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
    pass
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: intents = discord.Intents.default()
AttributeError: module 'discord' has no attribute 'Intents' thats the error i get now

Comment: also my discord.py version is the 1.5.1

Comment: nvm no wait i wasnt wtf thx for the help

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### **The error tells you exactly what to do.**

1. Go to https://discord.com/developers/applications
2. Navigate to your application
3. Go to the `Bot` section
4. Scroll down and enable `SERVER MEMBERS INTENT`

Comment: "Presence Intent" is also required to be checked.

Comment: Not for this question, no. @WillWu Presence intent is needed to see other users presence.