# How do I make my bot writhe a welcome message in a chat?

Tags: python, discord.py

Hello Guys I am trying to make my bot writhe a welcome message in a specific chat and using this code.
But nothings happening and I don't know why

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks


intents = discord.Intents(messages=True, guilds=True, reactions=True, members=True, presences=True,)
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='Ayaka ')


@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    await client.get_channel(channelID).send(f"{member.name} has joined")

@client.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
    await client.get_channel(channelID).send(f"{member.name} has left")
    
client.run(Token)
```

Comment: This might be able to help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65371837/my-on-member-join-event-is-not-working-i-tried-intents-but-it-gives-this-error

Answer (score 1):

After defining the prefix, add a comma and put `intents=intents`. From experience, I've learned that the top line will only *define* intents.